# AAPT: error: resource style/com.applovin.mediation.MaxDebuggerActivity.Theme not found in android admob ads applovin mediation

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

I am trying to add applovin mediation adapter for admob ads in android project.

```
//Google AdMob AppLovin mediation
implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:9.15.2'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:applovin:9.15.2.0'
```

After adding the above dependencies I'm synchronized my gradle and run my project. I'm getting build error after applovin dependencies added.

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"...\build\intermediates\metadata_feature_manifest\adsDebug\metadata-feature\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":388,"startColumn":8,"endLine":392,"endColumn":86}}],"original":"...\build\intermediates\metadata_feature_manifest\adsDebug\metadata-feature\AndroidManifest.xml:389:9-393:87: AAPT: error: resource style/com.applovin.mediation.MaxDebuggerActivity.Theme (aka xxxx:style/com.applovin.mediation.MaxDebuggerActivity.Theme) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:processAdsDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> ...\build\intermediates\metadata_feature_manifest\adsDebug\metadata-feature\AndroidManifest.xml:389:9-393:87: AAPT: error: resource style/com.applovin.mediation.MaxDebuggerActivity.Theme (aka xxxx:style/com.applovin.mediation.MaxDebuggerActivity.Theme) not found.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've resolved this issue yet, but I'd highly recommend switching over to [MAX](https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation), their docs are straightforward and the product is taking the industry by storm.